# Unresolved reference in PyCharm

Tags: python, model, reference, pycharm

My models.py is

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
body = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

My admin.py is

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog1.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

to add in my administration a Post group for blog.

And my blog1/urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog1.models import Post

urlpatterns = [ url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all() .order_by("-date")[:25],
                                         template_name="blog1/blog1.html"))]
```

It says unresolved reference for my from blog1.models import Post code as in admin.py also. Can you resolve this issue, i am stuck at here.

Comment: PyCharm isn't always correct. It does a very good job, but resolving references correctly in a dynamic language is hard to get 100% right. Does your code work? If so, stop fretting about the hint.

Comment: What directory is your project root in PyCharm?